# FFMPEG: Convert into avi compatible with mpeg2 DVB-T tuner

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have mpeg DVB-T tuner which plays avi with codecs: xvid and mp3. But when i convert video with libxvid, libmp3lame tuner prints 'Don't support this type'.

What the command which successfully converts mine video.

I've used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vcodec libxvid -r 25 -b 2000k -acodec libmp3lame -ab 256k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vframes 600 -f avi out.avi
```

Comment: What was the exact ffmpeg command you used?

Comment: i've put it to the question

Comment: Also, what exact tuner do you have and are there any specifications for it? Sometimes something as simple as an incorrect bitrate is enough to displease a player that says it can play XviD.